# Excel write formula with python

Tags: python, excel

```
 worksheet.write_formula(f'N{j}',f'=SUMIF(A$2:A${len(df5)+1},I{j},H$2:H${len(df5)+1*365/12})')
```

I'm using this code above to write into my excel worksheet, however all of the cells in column N show zero. I believe it is because of the *365/12. When I run the code below the formula works fine in excel, but I need to add *365/12

```
         worksheet.write_formula(f'L{j}',f'=SUMIF(A$2:A${len(df5)+1},I{j},G$2:G${len(df5)+1})')
```

Comment: Do you want `*365/12` *outside* the parentheses?

Comment: I tried it outside of parenthesis, but I believe it still had a formatting issue in excel.

Comment: @BigBen When I put it outside the () the 365/12 doesn't show in the excel formula

Comment: worksheet.write_formula(f'N{j}',f'=SUMIF(A$2:A${len(df5)+1},I{j},H$2:H${len(df5)+1})*(365/12)')

Comment: This formula actually works above now.

Comment: Yeah, in other words, you want the `*365/12` outside the `SUMIF`.